# Unable to Find Last Row with Content in Excel VB

Tags: vba, excel

So I need to find the last row of two different columns.  The VBA code works for the first column, but then returns:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Application-defined or object-defined error.

The relevant variables are established here:

```
Set wsSource(0) = .Worksheets("CDF")
lStart = 6
Set wsTarget(1) = .Worksheets("Claim Edit Analysis")
lColumn = wsSource(0).Rows(1).Find(What:=lIDNumber, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
lColumnTwo = wsSource(0).Rows(1).Find(What:=lIDNumber2, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
lBillCol = wsSource(0).Rows(1).Find(What:=lBillNumber, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
lRow = 6
lCount = 0
```

I then Call a Public Sub

```
Call CDFExtract(lStart, wsSource(0), rnSource, wsTarget(Target), rnTarget, lColumn, lColumnTwo, lBillCol, lRow, lCount)
```

The Public Sub comes in and this is where the error comes up:

```
Public Sub CDFExtract(ByVal lStart As Double, ByRef wsSource As Worksheet, ByVal rnSource As Range, ByRef wsTarget As Worksheet, ByVal rnTarget As Range, ByVal lColumn As Double, ByVal lColumnTwo As Double, ByVal lBillCol As Double, ByVal lRow As Double, ByRef lCount As Double)

Dim iRowBrief As Long
Dim iRowBriefTwo As Long

    With wsSource
      iRowBrief = .Cells(Rows.Count, lColumn).End(xlUp).Row
      iRowBriefTwo = .Cells(Rows.Count, lColumnTwo).End(xlUp).Row
   End With
```

wsSource = the source worksheet

iRowBrief = variable where the first column's last row is being stored

lColumn = the first column where last row is found

iRowBrief2 = variable where the second column's last row is trying to be stored

lColumnTwo = the second column where last row needs to be found

As you can see, the code is literally the exact same.  Why am I receiving this error?

Comment: Where do you set the values for `lColumn` and `lColumnTwo`?

Comment: I will bet that `lColumnTwo` = 0 at that time.  Double check you do not have a typo and that you actually assign a value to it before using it.

Comment: the syntax to set lColumn and lColumnTwo are the exact same.  I've even added a MsgBox to tell me what lColumnTwo is and it spits out "11" so I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Please show them, again my guess is that you have a typo and are using two different variables that look similar but are not and the one you are using in the offending line is different than the one that gets a value assigned.

Comment: lColumn = wsSource(0).Rows(1).Find(What:=lIDNumber, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column

Comment: lColumnTwo = wsSource(0).Rows(1).Find(What:=lIDNumber2, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column

Comment: Then both are used in a Public Sub, brought in ByVal "ByVal lColumn As Double, ByVal lColumnTwo As Double", you were correct though it is showing the lColumnTwo as not holding a value, but it has a value of 11 before the other sub begins

Comment: Please add clarifications to the original post and not in the comments.  I would post all the code that pertains to this error including all declarations and how the value is assigned.

Comment: For us to help, I think you are going to have to post (in the question, not in comments) the bits of your code where the value of `lColumnTwo` is being set, and where it is calling the subroutines, and explain the order of calling the subroutines (e.g. if the variable is set in the subroutine where it is a ByVal parameter, it will be zero outside that subroutine).

Comment: How on earth can `wsSource(0)` work?

Comment: @SJR There is a possibility that the posted code is a "MCVE" version, and that the OP actually has an array of worksheets.  (But it could also be a bug :D)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve]. **A proper MCVE reproduces the issue at hand**. This code doesn't, and wastes everyone's time.

Comment: @YowE3K *~whistles~*

Comment: @YowE3K - quite so, the OP clearly likes to keep everyone guessing.

Comment: I tried to add all relevant code, sorry for that

Comment: If you have `On Error Resume Next` above the top snippet, and the `Range.Find` calls fail, you're shoving a run-time error 91 under the carpet and happily passing `0` for a column index to your procedure - and `0` isn't a valid column for `.Cells` to work with. So either `lColumn` or `lColumnTwo` is zero, you can find out by placing a breakpoint (F9) on `With wsSource` and then inspecting your parameter values.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Come on - read the comments and not just the question ;) - "you were correct though it is showing the lColumnTwo as not holding a value, but it has a value of 11 before the other sub begins"

Comment: @Mat'sMug yeah the issue is with lColumnTwo, you're right it is passing a zero through.  I don't know why though, because before the other Sub is called it 100% holds a value of 11.  I checked with a MsgBox.

Comment: @YowE3K sorry, couldn't be bothered to keep up with that mess! ...but oh look ^^^^^

Comment: @Mat'sMug my bad for the clutter, really have never posted here before

Comment: Put your breakpoint at the assignment of `lColumnTwo`, and step throught the code (F8) with the "Locals" toolwindow open. FWIW column numbers should be `Long`, not `Double`. `Double` is a floating-point type.

Comment: Scratch that, I've no idea. Even if it's shadowed, it would still have the correct value.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yeah - a declaration within `CDFExtract` would give a "multiple declarations" error.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Is there any chance at all that the old `Call` methodology could be corrupting the parameter references being placed on the call stack?

Comment: @YowE3K https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLEnJ.png - RE `Call`: I really hope not.. I've been telling people `Call` is just an outdated way to make procedure calls... *that implicit procedure calls do **exactly** the same thing*...

Comment: @Mat'sMug Ahh - I was thinking you meant a declaration within `CDFExtract` that was shadowing the parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158641/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-yowe3k).

Comment: @Mat'sMug Sorry - can't chat - my work blocks it.  (And I guess I really should stop chatting in comments anyway, and get back to [or start] work :D)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to put a dot in front of the rows.count?

```
With wsSource

        iRowBrief = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        iRowBriefTwo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lColumnTwo).End(xlUp).Row

End With
```

Comment: Where that is good practice it will not be the cause of the error.  This only errors when working with multiple workbooks where one is an .XLS and the other .XLSX